# Iterate through Array of objects and if all key values equal the same return true else false Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the below array of objects I basically want to compare the values in the language keys and if all are the same return true else return false. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
var list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Daniel', lastName: 'J.', country: 'Aruba', continent: 'Americas', age: 42, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Kseniya', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Belarus', continent: 'Europe', age: 22, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Hanna', lastName: 'L.', country: 'Hungary', continent: 'Europe', age: 65, language: 'JavaScript' },
];  

function isSameLanguage(list) {
  let counter =0;

  for (let i=0; i<=list.length; i++){
    counter = counter = counter +1
    if (list.language[i] == list.language[i]){
      //console.log("Match")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for the is the [every method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). In your case it'd look something like this:

```js
function isSameLanguage(list) {
  if (!list.length) return false; // guard to prevent the next line from throwing an error

  const firstLanguage = list[0].language;

  return list.every(item => item.language === firstLanguage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need a counter variable.
2. `list.language[i] == list.language[i]` in the context of your data doesn't make sense. It's the index of the *object*, not the index of the language. So: `list[i].language`, and you can compare that to the next element in the array: `list[i].language !== list[i + 1].language`. If they don't match return from the loop ("No match"), otherwise, wait for the loop to complete ("Match").

Example one where they all do match:

```js
const list1=[{firstName:"Daniel",lastName:"J.",country:"Aruba",continent:"Americas",age:42,language:"JavaScript"},{firstName:"Kseniya",lastName:"T.",country:"Belarus",continent:"Europe",age:22,language:"JavaScript"},{firstName:"Hanna",lastName:"L.",country:"Hungary",continent:"Europe",age:65,language:"JavaScript"}];

function isSameLanguage(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
    if (list[i].language !== list[i + 1].language) {
      return 'No match';
    }
  }
  return 'Match';
}

console.log(isSameLanguage(list1));
```

Example two where they don't:

```js
const list1=[{firstName:"Daniel",lastName:"J.",country:"Aruba",continent:"Americas",age:42,language:"JavaScript"},{firstName:"Kseniya",lastName:"T.",country:"Belarus",continent:"Europe",age:22,language:"JavaScript"},{firstName:"Hanna",lastName:"L.",country:"Hungary",continent:"Europe",age:65,language:"JavaScript2"}];

function isSameLanguage(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
    if (list[i].language !== list[i + 1].language) {
      return 'No match';
    }
  }
  return 'Match';
}

console.log(isSameLanguage(list1));
```

Comment: Thanks Andy this has really helped me. Is my understanding of this correct?                           We have a For loop that iterates through the entire array of objects as it terminates the loop when the list.length value is met, for each iteration of the for loop we execute an if statement that takes the current list element i and compares it to the next element i value using +1 if they are not equal to each other return false else return true?  I am new to coding and I want to know exactly what my code is doing:0) Thanks for your help KInd regards, Jon

Comment: If the condition isn't met the function returns immediately, but if the condition is met the loop carries on until the final iteration when it finally returns. Good luck with the coding!

Comment: Thanks Andy your help is much appreciated have a great day!